# Getting Dimensions of Marquee Tool in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools, marquee-tool

Is it possible to get the dimensions (width, height, top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right) of the select area that is selected using the marquee tool.

If yes how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bringing up the Info window gives you exactly all that information.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [Lauren Ipsum's](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/52/lauren-ipsum) [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/347/getting-dimensions-of-marquee-tool-in-photoshop/348#348) for looking up to the `Info` window, which shows the width and height, you can get the coordinates for different reference points by choosing:

`Edit` → `Free transform` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> on OS X)

Then the X & Y coordinates for the specified/dragged reference point are shown in the Free transform toolbar.

Comment: +1 yeah figured this lol. but i need to change that % intp px first then it will show I guess.

Comment: True. For the coordinates, though, this might be more useful. (It also seems that if you change the unit in the toolbar, Photoshop remembers your choice for the rest of the session)

Comment: Yeah but for the first time we have to change it.